# make purely css animated icons cross browser compatible

Tags: html, css

I have some css animated weather icons that I would like to make cross browser compatible, right now they are working perfectly in firefox, I'm working on google chrome compatibility.

As it is just too much code, I've just setup a fiddle.  [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kcf44udg/).

I have added all the

```
-webkit-...
```

additions to transform and animation and to the keyframes, but there is still a little bug you can see in the fiddle, when hazy and following are up:

**Chrome**:

[image]

the desired behaviour at this point is:

**Firefox**:

[image]

I don't get what else I could do, maybe someone here knows better.

Comment: I think so too after reading the code over and over again. I just can't see why the cloud won't change. Is any of the animations or transformations simply not chrome confirm? @Dai Thanks.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I reduced your case to a simplified version containing only clouds: http://jsfiddle.net/kcf44udg/1/ and I noticed a few cases where your `-webkit`-prefixed properties didn't match the non-prefixed versions (so it isn't a bug in Chrome at all):

```
.cloud .cloud1:not(.c_shadow) ul li{
    animation: cloudi 10s 0.1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cloudi 10s 0.1s linear infinite;
}

.cloud .cloud1:not(.c_shadow):before{
    animation: cloudi 10s 0s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cloudi 10s 0s linear infinite;
}
```

You're missing the `cloudi` in the `-webkit-animation` lines.

Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/kcf44udg/2/

Comment: For cases like this I like the autoprefixer tool for grunt, write it once, it will take care for the rest, no mistakes like this happening.

Comment: I personally used this: https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer but I guess they are the same basically (Seems like the one I posted is just a grunt wrapper around the postcss tool) :)

Comment: @Dai thank you for the tip with the autoprefixer, this is just awesome!